# помогите корректно установить протобуфф

Tags: google-protobuf, protoc

попробовал установить тензорфло при помощи юпитер нотебук и столкнулся с проблемой не могу правильно установить протобуфф. все устанавливается в переменной среде при помощи юпитер нотебук.

```
!cd {paths['PROTOC_PATH']} && tar -xf protoc-3.15.6-win64.zip
    os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + os.path.abspath(os.path.join(paths['PROTOC_PATH'], 'bin'))   
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && copy object_detection\\packages\\tf2\\setup.py setup.py && python setup.py build && python setup.py install
    !cd Tensorflow/models/research/slim && pip install -e .
```

как в этом коде установить protobuf package to 3.20.0.
спасибо